# How to use table functions in queries with Spring Data

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-data

When using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate, what are the options available to write queries that join with [table functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS).

For example, I'd like to generate queries as described below:

```
CASE 1: SELECT * FROM getfoo(1) AS t1;

CASE 2: SELECT * FROM getfoo(1) x INNER JOIN tbl1 y on x.id = y.id;
```

**Edit**
To elaborate more, I'm using Spring Data for all things CRUD (It works great). However, I need  to write complicated queries that join tables with "table functions". Table functions(AKA Table-Valued User-Defined Functions) are database functions that return tabled-values which can be used in the JOIN clause in combination with tables. Postgresql and Sql Server support them.

In the Spring Data realm, which includes much more than JPA, what are the options to consider when writing such queries? Whats the best practice from your experience? user2658013 was kind enough to describe one such approach using the entityManager.reateNativeQuery method.

In my mind here are the options:

- JPA

  - Use @NamedStoredProcedureQuery ( >=JPA 2.1)
  - Use entityManager.createNativeQuery or @NamedNativeQuery
- Non-standard

  - Use Spring Data's @Query to declare finder queries directly on repository methods.
  - Use SimpleJdbcCall
  - Any others?

Comment: When using Spring Data JPA, then you use JPA. Within JPA you have Entities and its Relations and you wite JPA-Queries at this level. But not at the level of tables. - But maybe I understand your question wrong, then please explain your problem a bit more.

Comment: 1. you could use a view. 2. JPA 2.1 supports store procedures, but you'd have to use eclipselink for now

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Thanks, Hibernate >= 4.3.1.Final supports JPA 2.1

Comment: @Ralph, I've further edited the question with more context. To your point, you are right, however, I'm wondering if there is anything else under the Spring Data umbrella that helps to deal with these sort of queries with respect to type-safety, keeping things  DRY, and, say, function/procedure mapping even outside the JPA realm.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking about Postgres stored functions. Postgres stored functions are analogous to "Stored Procedures". So I think you are asking how would invoke a stored procedure using JPA? Am I close?

The following pseudo code is derived from details published here (see section on Stored Procures):
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
SOMEVAL_TYPE result = (SOMEVAL_TYPE)em.createNativeQuery("SELECT getfoo(?1) FROM SOMEDB")
                      .setParameter(1, SOME_PARM)
                      .getSingleResult();
```

In general you can use JPQL with JPA instead of SQL.

Note! The above assumes you have already created the stored function in you Postgres database.

Hope that helps :)